# Validate email with certain domain with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, expression

I've been playing around with this expression for an hour now and I can't seem to get it to work. I need to validate an email with a certain domain. The email must be in the format:

firstname.lastname@abc.domain

The domain could be either .ca .com or .org and the first and last name must be between 4 and 10 characters. This is the code I have right now

```
/^[a-z]{4,10}\.[a-z]{4,10}[@]abc\.(com|ca|org)$/i
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works fine here with `preg_match`. What isn't working for you?

Comment: Works here: http://regexr.com?32jfd

Comment: my last name is larger than 10 characters, and my friend MAX, has a 3 letter first name, why the restriction on size?

Comment: @Dagon: the asker has a very restrictive format.  `filter_var()` is overkill in this particular case.  If it didn't appear that he was trying to restrict this to a very specific format and domain, I would agree with you though.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Does it not match at all or does it match the wrong things? Also, could you paste the code this regex is used in?

Comment: Ah it was another thing wrong in my code, this expression works now. Thank you anyways and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Crontab, you are replying to a deleted comment ;)

Comment: @Dagon: You're a sneaky guy.  =)

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeking to validate an email address it is already handled sufficiently by using

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php